# How to add image in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uitableview

I have to add image in tableview in each. I have 2 list one is for twitter and second is for facebook. I want to show each list with their image icon. here is my code to attach value in table of twitter.

```
   for (NSDictionary *wallText in sortedarray) {

    NSString *wallNameValue = [wallText objectForKey:@"message"];


    if(![[NSNull null] isEqual:wallNameValue] && [wallNameValue length])
    {


        [tableList addObject:wallNameValue];

    }

}
```

I want to show twitter image in left of row. How will i add image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try using in this Way:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imagedNamed:[wallText objectForKey:@"message"]];
```

& plus there is no need to run any loop for this.This is optimize your code.

Just access the array via **indexpath.row**

```
NSDictionary *wallText = (NSDictionary *)[[sortedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:message];
```

Hope you are going to do all these things in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath .

Answer (score 0):

In your table view's delegate, in the method that sets up your UITableViewCell's, do something like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = myImage;
// myImage is a UIImage *.
```

Every UITableViewCell comes with a UIImageView built in that displays an image for you on the left side of the cell.

Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just do

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[yourImageDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: It will fix image. I have 2 for loop one is showing facebook data and 2nd loop is showing twitter data. I want to add both facebook and twitter image with their row data.